# encoding the contents of assets folder in android cordova app

Tags: android, cordova, obfuscation, minify, yuglify

We are developing a cross platform mobile application. Using apache cordova for this. Our android project structure is like given below,

```
Project
-   src
-   gen
-   assets
-   bin
-   res
```

One of the issue we are facing is, once we build the apk file, anyone can unzip the apk and see the files (html, js, css) in **assets** folder. Can we encode, uglify, minify or obfuscate these files? We are not using any automated build tools. Building apk using eclipse & adt plugin.

Any help much appreciated